# Integral of pointwise max function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Consider given some functions $f_1,f_2,g\in C^\infty([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ which have both positive and negative values. Call $F:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the pointwise maximum of $f_1$ and $f_2$: $F(x):=max\{f_1(x),f_2(x)\}$. Suppose it is true $\int_a^bf_1gdx\ge 0$ and $\int_a^bf_2gdx\ge 0$. Then is it always true $\int_a^bFgdx\ge 0$? I suspect the answer is yes, but I can't work out a formal proof.

Comment: Use the fact that $\max\{ f_1, f_2\} = (f_1 + f_2 + |f_1 -f_2|)/2$.

Comment: thank you, but then what should I do with $\int_a^b|f_1-f_2|gdx$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is false. As a counterexample, let $[a,b] = [-1,1]$, and
\begin{align*}
  g(x) &= -1 \\
  f_1(x) &=
    \begin{cases}
      -2 & x \lt 0 \\
       1 & x \ge 0
    \end{cases} \\
  f_2(x) &=
    \begin{cases}
      1 & x \lt 0 \\
      -2 & x \ge 0
    \end{cases}
  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Observe that $\int_{[-1,1]} f_1 g = \int_{[-1,1]} f_2 g = 1$, but $\int_{[-1,1]} F g = \int_{[-1,1]} -1 = -2$.

Now, I know you asked for a smooth functions, and that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are not smooth. However, the fundamental problem is present with or without the smoothness requirement (for any $\epsilon$, you can convert these into smooth functions without changing the relevant integrals by more than $\epsilon$), and it's easiest to see for piecewise defined functions.

Comment: thank you, but what if both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are positive functions?

Comment: @User29983 Thank you for your interest in my answer. In the future, please refrain from editing questions to significantly change their meaning, especially after they've received answers. This policy is out of consideration for the people who take the time to answer questions, to ensure that their efforts aren't spent chasing moving goalposts. If you'd like to ask a new question, you should do so with an actual new question on the site. You can even put a link to this question in your new question and say that you needed an additional assumption to get what you were looking for.

Comment: @User29983 See, for example [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304/question-edited-to-change-meaning) post on the meta-site.

Comment: Take for example $[a,b] = [-\pi, 2\pi]$ with $g(x) = \sin x$, let $f_1$ be $1$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ and $0$ on $(\pi,2\pi]$ and let $f_2$ be $0$ on $[-\pi,0)$ and $1$ on $[0,2\pi]$. Smooth it. (add a constant if you want strictly positive $f_1,f_2$)